# Fire another API call in Lifecycle callbacks - Strapi

Tags: mongoose, strapi

I have two content Types: Products and TempBaskets

Products contains a field; `stock-total` which I'd like to change based on TempBaskets being created or updated with this shape:

```
{ 
 "products":{
   "test-product": {
     "quantity":1,
     "id":"5b945b5b91f2d31698893914",
     "price":123
   }
 },
 "id":"5bb6a2c34f119f72182ec975",
 "totals": {
   "items":1,
   "price":123
 }
}
```

I want to catch this data in TempBaskets lifecycle hooks, then call one of Products controllers and update test-product's stock by -1.

```
afterUpdate: async (model, result) => {
    console.log(model);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(model.products); // undefined
    console.log(model.body); // undefined
    console.log(model.data); // clutching at straws - undefined 
}
```

`model` and `result` are mongoose objects. The docs seem to suggest `model.products` should contain the data I need - but it's undefined.

How do I access the data from a call in the lifecycle methods?

Can I then use the controllers from Products in the lifecycle hooks?

Lastly, (sorry stack overflow gods) is this the correct approach?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this, and I'm not sure if this is the perfect approach, but here's how I tackled it.

```
// Before updating a value.
// Fired before an `update` query.
beforeUpdate: async function(model) {
  // Get _id of project being updated
  let documentId = model._conditions._id;
  // Tack it on to the middleware chain so it can be used in post save hook
  this.documentId = documentId;
},

// After updating a value.
// Fired after an `update` query.
afterUpdate: async function(model, result) {
  // Pull the updated project
  let updatedDocument = await this.findById(this.documentId);
},
```

Note the change in `async (model) => {}` to `async function(model){}`. Mongoose middleware runs as a chain, so you can pass data from the pre-hook to the post-hook. This feels like it's making an extra database call, but I'm not sure there's any ways around this due to how Mongoose works.